# does JDK 6 support all features of XPath 2.0?

Tags: java, xpath, xpath-2.0

like `for`, `sum`, `if`, `intersect`...and if not, or not entirely, where can I find the details? And if it does, where can I find an official confirmation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html), Java 6 supports [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)

This is still [true as of Java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html).

Comment: as always, RTFM saves the day. My bad, didn't look close enough. Thank you, McDowell

Comment: "Support" is a terrible word, it should be banned from the lexicon. The XPath processor bundled with Java 6 is an XPath 1.0 processor. There are a number of XPath 2.0 processors available that work with Java 6 but are not part of Java 6, including Saxon and PsychoPath. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: @Michael Kay - I used "support" because I am not really aware of the inner workings of XPath and JDK and thus could not have used "bundled processor" or such :) Unfortunately I am restricted to pure JDK unless I can provide a 
**major** reason to use an external lib...which I can't because the "shortcomings" of XPath 1.0 can be resolved programmatically. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Java is a programming language and it doesn't have direct language constructs, especially designed for evaluating XPath expressions.

It is totally different that some classes can come bundled with the Java distribution, that implement an XPath engine.

AFAIK, these XPath-engine implementing classes at present only implement XPath 1.0.

Of course, there are a number of 3rd party Java-based products, such as Saxon, which I am using every day in my free time. Another one I have seen mentioned is PsychoPath.

Comment: You're right - it was a typical case of confusing the language with the libs provided with the JDK on my part :) I will change the title accordingly. Unfortunately I am restricted to the JDK, as the policy in our current project is to avoid using 3rd party libs. It is surely very arguable, but it's not my call.

Comment: @kostja: I am glad my answer was useful. Please, feel free to upvote/accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Java 6 does, but I'm pretty sure Saxon (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) does.