# xpath 2.0 for java possible

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, jdom

What package shall I use for XPath? I want wo query for elements and then extract some values around these nodes. Maybe one or more levels higher, some attributes.

`javax.xml.xpath` is XPath 1.0. Is `javax.xml.xpath` and `org.w3c.dom` the right way to go, or are there more modern implementations? `org.w3c.dom` is very awkward, JDOM seems alot easier.

Comment: If you want XPath 2.0 you need an external implementation added to your classpath.  What is it you need from 2.0?

Comment: That's way I don't yet know. It's a very generic tool that accepts xPath as input. So I want something good for the future. Maybe Jaxon?

Comment: In that case why start with the XPath 1.0 in the standard runtime library and make that work first?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two possible tools to use.

Comment: The built-in JDK implementation of XPath uses XPath 1.0, at least through Java 17 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5803028/411282)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**You may consider a Java-based XPath 2.0 or XQuery implementation (the XSLT 2.0 choice provides much more powerful functionality), such as [Saxon 9.x](http://www.saxonica.com)**.

Saxon is open source and one of the highest quality java-based processor so far and I am using it on a daily basis when answering SO XSLT/XPath/XQuery questions. In the documentation you will find good code examples.

The only stand-alone XPath 2.0 implementation I am aware of is [**PsychoPath**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PsychoPathXPathProcessor), but I am not sure of its quality and usability.

Comment: Has anything changed, are there any other alternatives? Struggling to find anything on the topic.

Comment: @IgorG. I am not aware of any new players in this field. There is now XPath 3.0 and 3.1, but these are usually encorporated in XSLT or XQuery processors, such as Saxon, BaseX, Marklogic, etc. It would be good to have a standalone XPath 3 processor.