# Can xpath 2.0 be used in java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, shared-libraries

I have a problem that requires I use max() which is only usable in xpath2.0, are there any libs that support this that I could drop in?

Thanks.

Comment: Asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6624149/422353

Comment: see whether following stack overflow thread helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624149/xpath-2-0-for-java-possible

Comment: I saw that thread, but it was a little over a year outdated,xpath 2.0 was fairly new so I assumed the thread to be way outdated by now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have a look for the Saxon implementation. Why Apache Xalan has stopped dead at XSLT 1 is another question.